# What are the solutions to $x+x^{-1}\bmod{n}\equiv2\bmod{n}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I've been playing around with this equation, and I don't have any solid footing to prove this is the case, but I do know the following.

- $1$ is always a solution.
- $n-1$ will only be a solution when $n=4$ because by definition $(n-1)^{-1}\bmod{n}\equiv n-1\bmod{n}$, and $2(n-1)\bmod{n}\equiv n-2\bmod{n}$. And, as we can see, $3+3\bmod{4}\equiv2\bmod{4}$.
- In a similar vein, $2$ will never be a solution because $2^{-1}\bmod{n}\equiv\frac{n+1}{2}\bmod{n}$. Then, $2+\frac{n+1}{2}\bmod{n}\equiv\frac{n+5}{2}\bmod{n}$, and setting $\frac{n+5}{2}\bmod{n}\equiv2\bmod{n}$ gives us $n+5\bmod{n}\equiv5\bmod{n}\equiv4\bmod{n}$. From here, it is plain to see that there are no non-trivial solutions for $n$.

Where can I go from here? Is my logic sound to begin with? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Note that multiplying both sides by $x$  would make your equation imply that $(x-1)^2\equiv 0 \pmod n$

Comment: How would you solve $x + \frac1x = 2$ in other contexts? Try to do things as similarly as possible. Take care about whether the algebraic rules you're relying on apply in the "mod n" context.

Comment: The occurence of "mod n" twice is confusing. Do you just mean $x+x^{-1}\equiv 2\mod n$ ?

Comment: @Peter that is what I meant, sorry

Comment: try $n=9$ and $n=25$  and $n=49$

Comment: @AKemats Instead of apologizing in a comment, edit the question to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

For $1/x$ mod $n$ to exist, we require $x$ relatively prime to $n$.  Then "multiply by $x$" is bijective on the integers mod $n$.  Follow Jaimie's hint; deduce
\begin{align}
x+\frac{1}{x} \equiv 2 \pmod{n}
&\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad x^2+1 \equiv 2x \pmod{n}
\\&
\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad (x-1)^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{n}
\end{align}
If $n$ is square-free, this means $x \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$.
If $n$ is not square-free, then there are other solutions as well.
For example: if
$n=12 = 2^2\cdot 3$, then we can take $x-1 \equiv 0$ or $6$, so $x\equiv 1$ or $7\pmod{12}$.
If $n=216 = 2^3 3^3$, then $x-1 \equiv $ one of $2^3 3^3, 2^2 3^2, 2^3 3^2, 2^2 3^3$, so $x \equiv$ one of $1, 37, 73, 109$.